# Showing a subset of a vectorspace is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Having trouble showing whether these two subsets W within the given vectorspace V are

a) $V = \mathbb{R}^2, W = \{(a_1 , a_2) | sin(a_1) = a_2\}$

b) $V = \mathbb{R}^3,  W = \{(a_1 , a_2 , a_3) | (a_1 + a_2 + a_3)^2 = 0\}$

Pretty certain that a is not a subspace intuitively and b is a subspace but I don't know how to show it.
I understand what makes a subspace and have showed the zero vector is in both of them but don't know how to show it without loss of generality.

Comment: If $(a_1,a_2) \in W$ is $(2 a_1, 2 a_2) \in W$?

Comment: For b) note that the constraint is the same as $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x,y\in W$

Then $x=(x_1,\sin x_1)$ and $y=(y_1,\sin y_1)$

If $\lambda x+\mu y\in W$ for any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ then $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

$z=\lambda x+\mu y=(\lambda x_1+\mu y_1,\lambda \sin x_1+\mu \sin y_1)$

as $z_2\ne \sin z_1$ we can conclude that $W$ is *not* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

part (b)

Let $a,b\in W$ then $(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2=0;\;(b_1+b^2+b^3)^2=0$

Now consider $ha+kb=(ha_1+kb_1,ha_2+kb_2,ha_3+kb_3)$

$(ha_1+kb_1+ha_2+kb_2+ha_3+kb_3)^2=[h(a_1+a_2+a_3)+k(b_1+b_2+b^3)]^2=0$

Thus $ha+kb\in W$ for any $h,k\in\mathbb{R}$ therefore $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Hope this can be useful